# Why is phase reconstruction considered hard

Tags: signal-processing, speech-recognition

I am studying deep learning models for single channel speech separation.

I come across several recent methods:

- [Permutation Invariant Training](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06284)
- [Deep Clustering](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04306)
- [Deep Attractor Network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.08930)

All of these methods are using "masked" approach. This breaks down to:

1. Perform STFT on mixture signal to obtain spectra, then separate phase and power spectra.
2. Use power spectra of mixture as input feature, this drops phase information.
3. Feed input into a deep network, obtain some masks, typically within $[0.0, 1.0]$.
4. Multiply these masks with mixture power spectra to obtain power spectra of (estimated) separated signal.
5. Combine obtained power spectra with phase from mixture to reconstruct separated signal.

Why using masks? Why not estimate complex valued spectra directly?

Comment: Masked approach you are reading about is for signal separation, very different thing from phase reconstruction. Mask is needed when you want to remove guitar sounds from the song.

Comment: @Nikolay Shmyrev Thanks for the comment. I'm kinda new to this so probably not using terminology correctly. I meant, if we *don't* use masks, then we need to reconstruct the phase of estimated signal. The question is why this direct estimation often gives worse result.

Comment: I would change the title of the question then to point you are interested in phase reconstruction in specific case, not general phase reconstruction. And, this question much better fits http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent paper discussing complex separation mask (basically spectrum + phase estimation)

[Complex Ratio Masking for Monaural Speech Separation
Donald S. Williamson, Student Member, IEEE, Yuxuan Wang, and DeLiang Wang, Fellow, IEEE](http://homes.soic.indiana.edu/williads/publication_files/williamsonetal.cRM.2016.pdf)

They tried but it was not a great success. Most likely it is not due to the task is "hard", it is simply that they has not yet come with the right network architecture.

Also check

[Multi-talker Speech Separation with Utterance-level Permutation Invariant Training of Deep Recurrent Neural Networks
Morten Kolbæk, Student Member, IEEE, Dong Yu, Senior Member, IEEE, Zheng-Hua Tan, Senior Member, IEEE, and Jesper Jensen.](http://export.arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06284)

They also provide results for phase estimation for masks.